# Repeat random element if condition returns false

Tags: javascript, function, random

I am creating a Quiz where a randomly generated object property appears (object.name), and users input a text value to match an associated object property (object.number).  I have my function working (returns "Correct" when values match, "Incorrect when they don't), but I want the question to repeat until the user gets the answer correct.  Right now, even if the user inputs the incorrect value, a new question randomly generates.  Can you help me structure this so it repeats the same question until the user inputs the matching property value?

```
<body>
<h3 id="randThing"></h3>

<form name="userInputForm">

<input type="text" id="userIndexInput"></form>

<button type="button" id="enter" onClick="compareAnswer()">Validate</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function object(name, value)
{
this.name=name;
this.value=value;
}
var car=new object("Car","50333");
var desk=new object("Desk","10420");
var monkey=new object("Monkey","11450");

var a = [car,desk,monkey];
var randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())];

var specificThing = randomValue;
document.getElementById("randThing").innerHTML=specificThing.name;
var specificThingValue = specificThing.value;

function compareAnswer() 
{

    var x = document.getElementById("userIndexInput").value;
    if (x === specificThingValue) 
    {
        alert("Correct!");
        document.getElementById("randThing").innerHTML=randomValue;
    } 
else 
    {
    alert("Try Again!");
    //don't know what to put here to make same the same specificThing generate again   until x === specificThingValue
    }
};



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is pretty much okay. I think you got confused with `randomValue` and `specificValue`.

Here is a simple way to achieve what you want.

```
function QuestionObject(name, value)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.value=value;
}
var car         = new QuestionObject("Car","50333");
var desk        = new QuestionObject("Desk","10420");
var monkey      = new QuestionObject("Monkey","11450");
var Questions   = [car, desk, monkey];
var randomValue;

function generateQuestion()
{
    document.getElementById("userIndexInput").value = "";
    randomValue = Questions[Math.floor(Questions.length * Math.random())];
    document.getElementById("randThing").innerHTML=randomValue.name;
}

generateQuestion();

function compareAnswer() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById("userIndexInput").value;
    if (x === randomValue.value) 
    {
        alert("Correct!");
        generateQuestion();
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("Try Again!");
    }
};
```

Just had to change the variable names a little. Here is a fiddle if you like to see this in action http://jsfiddle.net/RR2h4/3/.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That worked...BUT.  I left out a part of the code that I realize now is my problem: I'm using <body OnLoad="document.userInputForm.userIndexInput.focus();">, and I think that's throwing it off.  Any suggestions about getting around that and I'd be grateful!!

Comment: This too: <input id="userIndexInput" type="text" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('enter').click()">
I'm not sure if this would throw it off as well.  I'm going to look into events and event handlers first and see if that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!!! Just one question: could the variable names I was using screw it up? I took your working code, changed the variable names to what I wanted (like 'doc', and 'this.index=index') but it wouldn't work ???? I changed back to your names and it works! maybe i just missed one slight change or something....

Comment: ok, so I've got that "value" isn't just variable text, it's obviously required somewhere.  I'll figure it out.  thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome :) Try it yourself, if it doesnt work, please update the question with the latest code, I ll try and help you.